# How do I keep Data from a navigational popup form in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I have a MS Access database(I'm using 2007 users are using 2016 runtime)

When the users open reports I have a modal form that gets the date(query gets entire week that user input is in) that the user wants information about, the modal form closes once the report has been generated since the user no longer needs it.

My problem occurs when the user prints or changes layout of the report,
Some text fields give me #Name? or #Error since they reference the modal form(now closed) in their control source.

**How do I prevent this?**

If I put an invisible textfield referencing the date on the form, wont that date also become #Name? when trying to print

Answer (score 0):

store those values on your form as a global/public variable in a module. then instead of your report referencing the form, have it reference the variables on its open event. you do need a function that returns the variable , and that the report reads.